# MAX in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be a small one but i could find any , see this is how it is..

I have a sqlserver table with two columns and two rows , one of the column's name is **Number** and it has two rows with values

```
1. c7df055e-f8b5-4fc5-9c0a-8f59624c4022
2. 1234
```

When i query the table with this query `select max(Number) from table table_name`

Its giving the result `c7df055e-f8b5-4fc5-9c0a-8f59624c4022` , So how does **MAX** calculate the maximum value when any of the values contains characters, i have searched for this and found this

[For character columns, MAX finds the highest value in the collating sequence.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx)

But could understand better , so anyone please suggest a better explanation..

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you're comparing such different types of data, I'd say that any result from `MAX()` could equally be argued to be right and/or wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "number" column is a text type (evidenced by presence of alpha and hyphen chars). For text types, sorting is alphabetic, and letters are "higher" than numbers, so the value starting with "c" is greater than one starting with "1".

Sorting has nothing to do with the format if the value: If the first character of the alphanumeric value was a zero, you would have got "1234" as the max.

Answer (score 5):

Collating sequence refers to the definition of how the numeric codes translate to characters.  ASCII is a common collating sequence, for example; the byte "65" translates to the character "A", the byte "58" translates to the character "8" etc.

Most languages will compare character by character, comparing the underlying values.  So "c" is 99 ASCII, and "1" is 49 ASCII, so the string starting with "c" will be the larger value.  In general, lowercase letters are higher than upper case are higher than numbers, and other characters are all over the place.